Is there a way to reuse tests in xUnit?
Let's say that I have a type called Widget.
Widget
public class Widget
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item>? Items { get; set; }
}

I have written a validator for this using FluentValidation called WidgetValidator, and a suite of tests for this called WidgetValidatorTests.
WidgetValidatorTests
public class WidgetValidatorTests
{
    // the tests
}

Widget instances are used in multiple places within the application. I also have a WidgetInventory class.
WidgetInventory
public class WidgetInventory
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }

}

This also has a validator WidgetInventoryValidator.
WidgetInventoryValidator
public class WidgetInventoryValidator : AbstractValidator<WidgetInventory>
{
    public WidgetInventoryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be null.")
            .GreaterThan(0)
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be zero.");

        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Name cannot be null.");

        RuleForEach(x => x.Widgets)
            .SetValidator(new WidgetValidator());
    }
}

Now this is great and I can reuse the WidgetValidator here, but to properly test that the RuleforEach is correctly configured I need to replicate the tests I have in WidgetValidatorTests in my WidgetInventoryValidatorTests class and keep them in sync.
I don't see a good way of doing this with inheritance. So I was wondering, does xUnit have a solution for having a package of tests that you can reuse in multiple test suites?

I could suggest refactoring a little your validators to accept sub-vaidators through constructor parameters - this way you will more adhere to dependency injection principles :)
And also gain a way to better test validators.
First, refactored classes (I simplified a little your code):
public class Widget
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetInventory
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }

}

public class WidgetInventoryValidator : AbstractValidator<WidgetInventory>
{
    public WidgetInventoryValidator(IValidator<Widget> widgetValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be null.")
            .GreaterThan(0)
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be zero.");

        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Name cannot be null.");

        RuleForEach(x => x.Widgets)
            .SetValidator(widgetValidator);
    }
}

public class WidgetValidator : AbstractValidator<Widget>
{
    public WidgetValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be null.")
            .GreaterThan(0)
                .WithMessage("Id cannot be zero.");

        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotNull()
                .WithMessage("Name cannot be null.");
    }
}

And here are tests - with and without mocking to showcase differences:
public class ValidationTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test_WithoutMock_ReturnValidationError()
    {
        // Arrange
        var widgetValidator = new WidgetValidator();
        var inventoryValidator = new WidgetInventoryValidator(widgetValidator);
        var inventory = new WidgetInventory
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Foo",
            Widgets = new List<Widget>() { new() },
        };

        // Act
        var result = inventoryValidator.Validate(inventory);

        // Assert
        Assert.False(result.IsValid);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_WithMock_ReturnValidationResultAsMocked()
    {
        // Arrange
        var widgetValidatorMock = new Mock<IValidator<Widget>>();
        widgetValidatorMock
            .Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<FluentValidation.ValidationContext<Widget>>()))
            .Returns(new ValidationResult() { Errors = new List<ValidationFailure>() });
        var inventoryValidator = new WidgetInventoryValidator(widgetValidatorMock.Object);
        var inventory = new WidgetInventory
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Foo",
            Widgets = new List<Widget>() { new() },
        };

        // Act
        var result = inventoryValidator.Validate(inventory);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(result.IsValid);
    }
}


Thanks @Michal - I ended up doing what you suggested and used NSubstitute to mock the injected validator and verifying  that is was called.
